# Reverse string using recursion without specific seperators

Tags: c++, recursion

I have an assignment which requires "Recursively reads one character at a time from the text file  until a separator is encountered" -
Those non-separator characters are then displayed in reverse order, with the last character displayed being capitalized

Let's say file has below line and separator is !, white space and so on.

```
abc! ndtv
```

Expected output is:

```
Cba! Vtdn
```

I have written below code and I am getting the expected output — but one condition is I am supposed to do it using only two variables, and I am not able to do it with less than 3. Any pointers how to achieve it with 2 variables only?

```
int Reverse(ifstream &inFile, int level)
{
   int myInput;
   static int returnValue;
   static int levelofinterest;

   myInput = inFile.get();

   if (!(isspace(myInput)  || ((char)myInput == '.') ||
         ((char)myInput == '!')   || ((char)myInput == ',') ||
         ((char)myInput == '?')   || ((char)myInput == ';') ||
         ((char)myInput == ':')   || ((char)myInput == '\0')||
         myInput == EOF))
   {
       level++;
       Reverse(inFile,level);
   }
   else
   {
       levelofinterest = level;
       returnValue = myInput;
   }

   if(!(isspace(myInput)  || ((char)myInput == '.') ||
         ((char)myInput == '!')   || ((char)myInput == ',') ||
         ((char)myInput == '?')   || ((char)myInput == ';') ||
         ((char)myInput == ':')   || ((char)myInput == '\0')||
         myInput == EOF))
   {
       level--;
       if ((levelofinterest - 1) == level)
       {
           cout << (char)toupper(myInput);
       }
       else
       {
           cout.put((char)myInput);
       }
   }

   return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Y is it downgraded - without giving reason ?? - What so wrong with question ?

Comment: Well, one reason for it might that the question was tagged [tag:c] but the code clearly uses [tag:c++] constructs such as `cout << …`.  That is a moderately serious mistake; if you can't distinguish which programming language you are writing in, there problems somewhere (maybe the IDE you're using blurs the distinction for you).  It is not clear what you mean by 'only two variables'.  You have a file stream, a level, and an input character, plus two mysterious static variables which are always bad news in a recursive procedure.  You can probably do it with just the file stream and input.

Comment: [Marc-AntoineLortie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5104395/marc-antoine-lortie) asked: Given `int Reverse(ifstream &inFile, int level)`, could you provide more detail about parameter _level_?  Also, are there any constraints related to the variables to must use? More precisely, are you only allowed to use integers or are you able to use strings, stacks, or any other containers from the standard library?

Comment: [oneday](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3902763/oneday) responded: _level_ is primarily used / intended to count number of recursion levels: `while ((value = Reverse(inFile, 1)) != EOF) { cout.put(char(value)); }`  Regarding strings etc: just two `int` variables — nothing from library.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Touche -  Thanks for changing the tag to c++ ..but I guess keeping in mind crux of problem statement and asked question with constraint of not using library function .. not sure how the question wont be relevent to C...  Moving from Semantics ...you mention the solution can be achieved by just " You can probably do it with just the file stream and input " - Can you shed bit more light on how to achieve it ..  - it would be great if you can answer with some reference sample code/pointers ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code almost meets your requirements (but I'm not completely happy with it).  It has only one extra variable over and above the arguments to the function.  However, I altered the function signature — the code doesn't use the return value, so the function is defined as returning `void`.  It probably can be modified to meet your alternative calling convention and the loop structure outlined in your (transcribed) comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

static void Reverse(istream &inFile, int level)
{
    int c = inFile.get();
    if (c == EOF)
        return;
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        Reverse(inFile, level + 1);
        if (level == 0)
            cout << (char)toupper(c);
        else
            cout << (char)c;
    }
    else if (level > 0)
        inFile.unget();
    else
        cout << (char)c;
}

int main()
{
    while (cin)
        Reverse(cin, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I call the source code `recrevstr.cpp` and compiled the program (using `make`) with the command:

```
g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror recrevstr.cpp -o recrevstr
```

and then run it:

```
$ ./recrevstr <<< 'abc! ndtv'
cbA! vtdN
$
```

It takes various short cuts.  In particular, all non-alphabetic characters are delimiters.  It uses an `istream` rather than an `ifstream`, and the `main()` is configured so standard input (aka `cin`) is processed.  Like your sample code, it relies on a loop in the calling code to make sure the job is complete.  I start with level 0; it's trivial to start with level 1 instead.

Note that any code using `cout` with `<<` operators to produce output is inherently C++ and not directly applicable to C.  This effect can be neutralized by using `<cstdio>` and `FILE *` (and `stdin`), plus appropriate I/O functions, which could then make it bilingual, though there'd need to be conditional compilation to get the `std` namespace out of the way.

Comment: Thank you so much - your below line  - was the trick I was missing. All along I was trying to change the first character to uppercase while I was getting out the value from stack a.k.a  reversing the string- What you helped me understand is I can do it while burying the value itself.                                                                                                        if (level == 0)
cout << (char)toupper(c);